# policy status in script qlikview

Tags: expression, qlikview, renewal, qlik-expression

i script but there is some problems

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYvb6.png)

If there is multiple policies then i want first record which has min date always as "new" because this record came first against specific policy .. and other record which has same policy consider as "renew" but for last record of each policy is

if  todate is greater than current date then consider as renew.. if todate is less than consider than current date then consider as "lost"

and for new  another point if policy is complete in 1 year then then consider as "renew" if policy did not complete 1 year then consider "new"

Kindly check below link of file

also in excel file "exampee"  the last highlighted column what i wanted

[link](https://filebin.net/y9bja87wzozxkcw6)

what i tried

```
Load Distinct
 POLICY_NO as [Child Policy],      
 OLD_POLICY_NUMBER as [Parent Policy],
 UW_YEAR,
 Date(POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE) as [From Date], 
 Date(POLICY_EXPIRY_DATE) as [To Date],
 Policy_Effective_Year,
 Month_Difference,

            if((Policy_Effective_Year=Year(Today()) and
    UW_YEAR=Year(Today()) AND Month_Difference < 12),'NEW',
    if(year(POLICY_EXPIRY_DATE)=year(today())-1,'LOST','RENEW')

    ) AS STATUS


 FROM
```

table_1.qvd
(qvd);